# how to put value inside javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i want to use Ajax and my function name is takeData()
this is the script inside that function

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("news").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
x++;
document.getElementById("Lmore").innerHTML="<input type='button' value='Load More' onclick='takeData(x)'>";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="Loading";
}
```

the problem is at this line

```
x++;
document.getElementById("Lmore").innerHTML="<input type='button' value='Load More' onclick='takeData(x)'>";
```

how to get the value x inside the function takeData(x)..for example after if the x = 0, then x ++ = 1 -> after this, i want the function takeData become takeData(1), thats why i call takeData(x) , but it seems not working, maybe it send the "x" value instead the number value ?Please help .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try this:

```
document.getElementById("Lmore").innerHTML="<input type='button' value='Load More' onclick='takeData("+x+")'>";
```

It will pass as `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like

**updated** no need to use `single quotes` for `variable x`

```
document.getElementById("Lmore").innerHTML="<input type='button' value='Load More' onclick='takeData("+x+")'>";
```

Comment: They *could* do that, but I think the OP would benefit from being taught the nicer way to handle this stuff.

Comment: why must use '" while it can only use "